# How to set table section title from any Array object in iPhone.

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview

I have tableView, which I am getting data from array and also the number of section and section title also from array, but when I give section title from array it breaks the App.

Getting values in array:

```
   NSArray *tempArray =[[DataController staticVersion] startParsing:@"http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/getCategory.php"];

for (int i = 0; i<[tempArray count]; i++) {

    id *item = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *) item;
    ObjectData *theObject =[[ObjectData alloc] init];
[theObject setCategoryID:[dict objectForKey:@"CategoryID"]];

[theObject setCategoryTitle:[dict objectForKey:@"CategoryTitle"]];
    [theObject setCategoryDescription:[dict objectForKey:@"CategoryDescription"]];  
    [theObject setCategoryAddedByUserID:[dict objectForKey:@"CategoryAddedByUserID"]];
    [theObject setCategoryAddedDateTime:[dict objectForKey:@"CategoryAddedDateTime"]];
[categoryArray addObject:theObject];
    [theObject release];
    theObject=nil;

}


   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

   return [categoryArray count] ;
   }

   - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section


  {
[categoryArray objectAtIndex:section];

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

expect a string in return.

Try

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    ObjectData *theObject =[categoryArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return theObject.categoryTitle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an instance of `ObjectData` class into the `categoryArray`. The `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`method asks for an `NSString` object to set it as the header of the section. Check what you are returning in the `titleForHeaderInSection:` method. It has to be an `NSString` object.If you want to set the category title as your section header title, return the categoryTitle as

```
return [(ObjectData*)[categoryArray objectAtIndex:section] categoryTitle];
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,

```
 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection(NSInteger)section
     {
       return [[categoryArray objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:@"title"];//replace title with your key value
     }
```